# GRASS GIS 7 v.net.iso in the processing toolbox fails to iterate over nodes

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I have successfully created an iso map for a small area of a road network and three points with forward and backward arc costs. However when trying to iterate over the three nodes to produce a separate iso for each, after the first completes I receive the error;

"local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment See log for more details"

And the process terminates. While I could select each point in this example, I am testing for a much bigger exercise. Could anyone point me in the direction of a solution?

Specs - QGIS 2.18.4 64bit, Windows 7 64bit. 2 .shp files stored on a network drive.